# how to check string value if table tag is available and implement regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have this string variable which composes a text and html tags. how do i perform regex only within the html **table** tag? is this possible?

```
string input = "Hello,\nTRAVEL DETAILS\n<table border=\"1\">\n<tr>\n<th align=\"center\">Initial Travel Date</th>\n<th align=\"center\">Reference Number</th>\n<th align=\"center\">First Name</th>\n<th align=\"center\">Surname</th>\n<th align=\"center\">Main Reason</th>\n<th align=\"center\">Client ID</th>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n<td align=\"center\">{TRV TRL INIT.trn}</td>\n<td align=\"center\">{TRV REF NO.trn}</td>\n<td align=\"center\">{TRV FIRST NM.trn}</td>\n<td align=\"center\">{TRV SURNAME.trn}</td>\n<td align=\"center\">Internal Meeting</td>\n<td align=\"center\">{TRV CLIEN ID.trn}</td>\n</tr>\n</table>"

string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
return output;
```

i only need to remove the "\n" inside the table element

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse html. Use a real html parser _at least_ to get the inner text of an element first.

Comment: What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a way to eliminate the "\n" inside the table. but then it resulted for not using the regex. here's the updated codes

```
    string input = emailMessage.Message.Replace("\n<tr>\n", "<tr>").Replace("</th>\n", "</th>").Replace("\n</tr>", "</tr>")
        .Replace("</td>\n", "</td>").Replace("\n</table>", "</table>");
    string output = input;

    return output;
```

thank you to all of the comments and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control to parse the HTML string, get the table chunk and remove the new lines from there.

Or you can utilise `IHTMLDocument`, `IHTMLDocument2`, `IHtmlDocument3` ... up to 8 to parse the HTML. You need to include Mshtml.dll in your project references though.

Or use a 3rd party HTML parser.

Do not try to manipulate the raw string unless you wanna write your own HTML parser.

Comment: can you send me some link relating to the WebBrowser? that i can use for refernce?

Comment: just google it and it will give you dozens of links